# VB.Net Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code in VB.Net (Winforms) to simply loop through a `DataGridView` and hide rows that are not needed.

```
Private Sub Overview_Workstream_Sort_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Overview_Workstream_Sort.SelectedIndexChanged

    For Each row In Incident_Persons_List.Rows
        If Incident_Persons_List.Rows(CInt(row)).Cells(7).Value.ToString.Contains(Overview_Workstream_Sort.SelectedItem.ToString) Then
            Debug.Print("User found in workstream")
            Incident_Persons_List.Rows(CInt(row)).Visible = True
        Else
            Incident_Persons_List.Rows(CInt(row)).Visible = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

When the debugger gets to the first line of the `IF` statement, I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

I've been trying everything I can think of to understand why this is. I've looked up the fault, but everyone seems to have completely different issues when this exception is thrown.

Is it something to do with how I am doing a compare?

**UPDATE 1**

1. I have removed the `For Each` and replaced it with `For i = 0 to Incident_Persons_list.Rows.Count`
2. I have removed the `Cint` instruction
3. The `Try/Catch` as revealed that the actual exception being thrown is:

> Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made
>   invisible.

**UPDATE 2**

Everything is now working correctly with the below code:

```
 Private Sub Overview_Workstream_Sort_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Overview_Workstream_Sort.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            For i = 0 To Incident_Persons_List.Rows.Count - 1
                If Incident_Persons_List.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString.Contains(Overview_Workstream_Sort.SelectedItem.ToString) Then
                    Debug.Print("User found in workstream")
                    Incident_Persons_List.Rows(i).Visible = True
                Else


                    'Your code that will throw the Exception
                    Incident_Persons_List.CurrentCell = Nothing
                    Incident_Persons_List.Rows(i).Visible = False

            End If
        Next
        Catch ex As TargetInvocationException
            'We only catch this one, so you can catch other exception later on
            'We get the inner exception because ex is not helpfull
            Dim iEX = ex.InnerException
            Debug.Print(iEX.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show the **complete** exception details, the InnerException is crucial to find out what went wrong.

Comment: There is no inner exception, that's the problem I'm facing

Comment: Wrap this block of code in a try/catch structure, then examine the InnerExcpetion

Comment: @SuperPeanut : I sincerely doubt he'll get an InnerException by wrapping it in a Try/Catch-block. The InnerException is created by whatever threw the error, not the Try/Catch. If Visual Studio says that the InnerException is Nothing, then it'll most likely be so every time the error is thrown.

Comment: @VisualVincent According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) (in the Remarks) : _When created, the TargetInvocationException is passed a reference to the exception thrown by the method invoked through reflection. The InnerException property holds the underlying exception._ So I don't understand how InnerException can be Nothing...

Comment: On another way, are you sure `CInt(row)` actually works ?

Comment: @SuperPeanut : Because all TargetInvocationExceptions might not be the same? -- As for your second comment: It doesn't work, as `row` is a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow`. There we have the OP's problem.

Comment: @VisualVincent I think every TargetInvocationException has a InnerException property that has been set, at least I have never heard of one that is Nothing. because when anything is Invoked it is surrounded by a try/catch that will rethrow the TargetInvocationException. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TargetInvocationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> The exception that is thrown by methods invoked through reflection

How to find out what's going on (because that exception is not really helpfull) ?

You must surroung the calling block with a `Try/Catch` structure, and then examine the `InnerException` caught :

```
Try
    'Your code that will throw the Exception
Catch ex As TargetInvocationException
    'We only catch this one, so you can catch other exception later on
    'We get the inner exception because ex is not helpfull
    Dim iEX = ex.InnerException
    'Now you can do some stuff to handle your exception
Catch ex As Exception
    'Here you catch other kinds of Exceptions that could occur in your code, if you want to...
End Try
```

And depending on the InnerException, you can now correct your code.

Comment: Voted this as the answer as although this isn't explicitly the >Answer<, it's a fantastic method that helped me find the route cause of the issue without additional help

Comment: As an advice, you should use a try/catch in every sub which handle an event tied to an UI action. Because user action are the most unpredictable things in an application and this made them a good candidate for unexpected behavior. Also Keep in mind that the InnerException is not specific to TargetInvocationException. Always take a look on this property when you don't find enough information on the "first level".

Answer (score 2):

As your row variable is an enumerated element of Incident_Persons_List.Rows and not an index of the element in the collection I think you should replace.

```
Incident_Persons_List.Rows(CInt(row))
```

By

```
row
```

Or using a basic for structure instead of foreach. Somethink like

```
For row = 0 To Incident_Persons_List.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
   //SomeStuff
Next
```