# Blue Prism fails on Open Workbook

Tags: excel, blueprism

So, it's official, I'm going mad.

I've installed Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, .NET 4.7.1, SQL Server Express 2014, Blue Prism 6.0, Office 2010 Pro (32-bit). I just followed the default installation process for all the softwares and nothing else has been customized or changed in the OS. It's basically a vanilla installation.

When I try to use the Excel VBO action "Open Workbook", it fails with: "Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

Even if "Create Instance" is not mandatory to open a workbook, I've also tried to design the full workflow to make sure all inputs and outputs were provided.

[See the workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbgIc.png)

See the details:

> 04/04/2018 10:15:12 START: 'Start' Process: 'Test' Subsheet: 'Action 1'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 ACTION: 'Create Instance' Process: 'Test' Subsheet: 'Action 1'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 START: 'Start' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Initialise'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 END: 'End' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Initialise'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 START: 'Start' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Create Instance'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 CODE: 'Create Instance' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Create Instance'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 SUBSHEET: 'Set Events Enabled' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Create Instance'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 START: 'Start' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Set Events Enabled'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 SUBSHEET: 'CheckInstanceHandle' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Set Events Enabled'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 START: 'Start' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 CODE: 'Check Handle' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 DECISION: 'Is Handle Missing?' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 END: 'End' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 SUBSHEET: 'CheckInstanceHandle' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Set Events Enabled'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 CODE: 'Enable Events' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Set Events Enabled'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 END: 'End' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Set Events Enabled'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 SUBSHEET: 'Set Events Enabled' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Create Instance'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 END: 'End' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Create Instance'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:13 ACTION: 'Create Instance' Process: 'Test' Subsheet: 'Action 1'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 ACTION: 'Open Workbook' Process: 'Test' Subsheet: 'Action 1'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 START: 'Start' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Open Workbook'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 SUBSHEET: 'CheckInstanceHandle' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Open Workbook'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 START: 'Start' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 CODE: 'Check Handle' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 DECISION: 'Is Handle Missing?' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 END: 'End' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckInstanceHandle'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 SUBSHEET: 'CheckInstanceHandle' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Open Workbook'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 SUBSHEET: 'VerifyFileExists' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Open Workbook'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 START: 'Start' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckFileExists'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 CODE: 'File Exists?' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckFileExists'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 DECISION: 'Does File Exist?' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckFileExists'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 END: 'End' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'CheckFileExists'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 SUBSHEET: 'VerifyFileExists' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Open Workbook'
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 CODE: 'Open Workbook' Process: 'MS Excel VBO' Subsheet: 'Open Workbook' ERROR: Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
>   04/04/2018 10:15:14 ACTION: 'Open Workbook' Process: 'Test' Subsheet: 'Action 1' ERROR: Internal : Could not execute code stage
>   because exception thrown by code stage: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The file exists, can be opened in Excel and other Excel actions works fine (for example: create instance, activate workbook, show). The exact same installation works correctly on Windows 10. I've also tried to install all the available Windows 7 updates, and Office x64, but nothing changed.

Any idea?

Comment: In the link below they suggest to repair .net framework. Maybe that could help?

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_365hp/error-help-me-please-exception-has-been-thrown-by/00e3500a-e316-4805-a2a8-04d92216630e

Comment: in the link below they suggest to surround the code with Try & Catch method and extract the inner exception. It should explain more clearly what's the cause of the error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070996/vb-net-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped the `OpenWorkbook` code stage in a `Try...Catch` block and looked at the `InnerException` message. The error was:"Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))".
By googling the error I found a mismatch between the Office language and the Regional Settings.